# JQuery validation on not existing checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-validate

I have a JQuery DataTable that has checkboxes to select items in it. I added j
JQuery validation such that you can't submit the form without having at least selected one checkbox. Here is what my validation looks like:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("noApplicationSelected", function(value, element, params) { return $('.cbDisplay').length != 0; },'{0}');
$('[name="cbDisplay"]').rules('add', { noApplicationSelected: ['No checkbox selected'] });
```

Everything works fine but my problem is that if I for example add a filter in my DataTable search such that no entries are present (empty DataTable), and I try to submit the form, it submits even though I haven't selected any checkboxes.
The reason for that I think is because the validation can't bind the rules on the checkboxes because they do not exist.

How can I fix this problem?

**Edit 1:**
Would adding some validation that checks for whether the DataTable is empty and a checkbox is selected fix my problem? But the issue I see with that is what do I bind this validation to? I guess I could bind it to the select all/deselect all checkbox but that doesn't make sense

**Edit 2:**

Demo of the probelm: https://jsfiddle.net/mu79L32w/14/

Comment: You should not check for the html-elements that are currently rendered by the DataTables. Instead try to iterate over the data of the DataTable-Object.

Comment: You seem to be overcomplicating this.  Also, where is the HTML markup?  Where is the code that dynamically adds the inputs?

Comment: I added another update, hope that helps you understand my problem better @Sparky

Comment: In addition to all these updates, please just construct one working jsFiddle that demonstrates these issues.

Comment: @Sparky I added a jsFiddle example, type "a" in the search and hit submit https://jsfiddle.net/mu79L32w/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to find the inputs/checkboxes inside the displayed document, you only get the rendered elements of the datatables-element. This means it is possible that you will not find any checkbox-element in the document if the filter of datatables is used. **If a row is not displayed in the datatables-element it is removed from the rendered table** and as a result all elements inside that row are also not available for a wrapping form-element.

But you can iterate over the data/rows of the DataTable-Object with javascript.

Here is an example on how to test if any checkbox is checked when the form submits by using jquery-validates `submitHandler`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [
      { "data": "column_a" },
      { "data": "column_b" }
    ]
  });
  
  function isAnythingChecked() {
    let foundChecked = false;
    let inputs = table.rows().nodes().to$().find('input');
    for (let input of inputs) {
      if (input.checked) foundChecked = true;
    }
    return foundChecked;
  }
  
  $("#myForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      if (isAnythingChecked()) {
        alert('Yeah! A checkbox is selected');
        //form.submit();
      } else {
        alert('Oh no! No checkbox selected');
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">

  <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column A</th>
        <th>Column B</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox 1</td>
        <td>Test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox 2</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox 3</td>
        <td>ipsum</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  <table>

  <button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
  
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I will try this tomorrow. Can you take a look at my updated question and tell me if that could work?

Comment: Sure. There are several other approaches to this task that could work. For example: You could also listen for the inputs click events and track in a variable if any of the checkboxes are checked.

Comment: what do I bind the validation to tough? do I have to bind it to an element with a name attribute?

Comment: I assume you have a form around your table that you want do validate before/on submit. In that case you can't bind the validation to the checkboxes, since they are not part of the form-data when not rendered in table. One option i can think of is an invisble form-element (outside of the table) that holds the current number of selected elements.

Comment: That's a good idea! so bind the validation on a hidden input instead of the individual checkboxes correct?

Comment: This answer does not appear to have anything to do with the jQuery Validation plugin, which is what the OP is using and asking about.

Comment: @Sparky what approach would you take to solve this issue?

Comment: I added an simple validation with the jQuery-Validation library that do not need any hidden element on the form and uses the previous presented example.

Comment: Why would you jump out to do separate validation via the `submitHandler` when you can properly use this plugin in the first place?  It's even more verbose than the OP's attempt.

Comment: @Sparky because the author of the question is using DataTables.js and wants to be able to use the filter-input of that library. DataTables renders dynamically the content of the table, which is part of the form. If there is no checkbox to render, then there is no checkbox in the form.

Comment: Right, and the plugin can automatically handle dynamic inputs in several ways.  There's also no need to write functions that iterate through checkboxes to make them `required`.

Comment: @Sparky you're right I don't need to use any custom functions to validate checkboxed, required="required" worked fine for me. But what Jan is getting at is that I'm using the DataTable.js plugin and if you use any filters the checkboxes and data disappear from the screen which in turn disabled validation meaning you can submit a form without checking anything

Comment: @BigMon, if you are trying to validate hidden or invisible fields, they will be ignored.  This is a known feature of the plugin discussed in the documentation and in various SO questions.  Set the `ignore` option to `[]` ("nothing"), which is `ignore:  []` so that any hidden fields are validated.

Comment: @Sparky have you had the time to look at my jsFiddle demo link?

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, you cannot bind validation to any input that does not yet exist.

I don't see enough code for a demo, so some generics below:

1. You do not need to write a custom method for making checkboxes `required` using this plugin.  If the checkboxes are in a group sharing the same `name`, then `required` will make at least one from the group mandatory.  See:  [jsfiddle.net/q357zcwy/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/q357zcwy/1/)
2. The whole point of the `.rules()` method is for dynamically adding removing rules after the plugin has already been initialized on the form.  So if you dynamically add an `input`, then call `.rules()` on that `input` *after* it's been created.  See:  [jsfiddle.net/q357zcwy/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/q357zcwy/2/)
3. If you only want to add `required`, then the easiest way to handle this is by putting the `required="required"` attribute on the input and my item #2 above is negated.  You do not have to worry about whether it exists or when to call `.rules()`.  Simply create the `input` that includes this attribute and the plugin will automatically pick it up.  See:  [jsfiddle.net/q357zcwy/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/q357zcwy/3/)

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" name="foo" required="required" ....
   ```
4. Hidden or invisible fields are always ignored by default.  If your plugin is hiding any of the fields you are trying to validate, then you'll need to over-ride this behavior using the `ignore` option.  Set `ignore` to `[]`("nothing") so that nothing is ignored and everything gets validated.

   ```
   ignore: []
   ```

**EDIT**:  More notes after seeing [your jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mu79L32w/14/):

5. The `.validate()` method gets called once to initialize the plugin on the `form`.  [Typically on page load](https://jsfiddle.net/efsr7qv9/1/).  However, you have it within the function that is called by your `click` handler, which means validation is not initialized until the button is clicked and it's repeatedly called unnecessarily every time the button is clicked.
6. The DataTables plugin is indeed removing the rows entirely when you search/filter the table.  Although the validation plugin can handle invisible or hidden elements (see item #4 above), there is no way anyone can reasonably expect it to handle elements that no longer exist in the DOM.  I find it strange that DataTables can not merely hide these rows or render them invisible rather than removing entirely.
7. The solution by Jan is interesting as it iterates through the DataTables object looking for checked items.  However, there does not seem to be a way to properly integrate this function into the operation of the jQuery Validate plugin.  While the validate plugin is normally tied to each input and automatically shows/hides messages based on rules, this "workaround" is clumsily shoved into the `submitHandler`, which is normally only invoked ***after*** the form is valid.  It also cannot leverage the default validation messages, `highlight`, `unhighlight`, `success`, `invalidHandler`, or [any of the other built-in functions](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

There *might* be a way to leverage [`showErrors`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) to show & hide the default messages programmatically based upon the iteration through the DataTables object.  However, this workaround would get overly complex.  You would also need to gather the name(s) of the checked object from the DataTable object in order to know which messages to toggle. Then if none of the rows exist when you want to validate, you'd have to find another way to trigger validation.  Since nearly all of the default functionality of the jQuery Validation plugin would be over-written anyway, it might actually make more sense to just write your own form validation from scratch.  No off-the-shelf validation plugin is going to be able to handle input elements that don't exist.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I didn't know about any of the stuff you mentioned, so I appreciate it! can you take a look at my edit and let me know what you think is the best way to fix the validation of the non existing checkbox (due to the datatable filter being applied)

Comment: Just tested Datatables.js + jQuery-Validation. All three of your suggested approaches fail if the user did not selected a checkbox and the table is empty because of the datatables-filter. The form will submit without any error or warning.

Comment: @Jan - if the visible `input` is inside the `form` and the `required` rule is properly initialized, it *will* always validate.  So please construct a *complete* jsFiddle demo showing your observations... I'm not going to play this guessing game.

Comment: They are not hidden, they are removed from the document. Just look with dev-tools/inspector at the table in my example.

Comment: @Jan - I see that now.  Perhaps it would be best to update the wording of your answer as such.  *"if the active filter of the datatable **h̶i̶d̶e̶s̶ {removes}** all the rows"* ~ After all, like you said, they are not hidden.

Comment: @Sparky Yeah, your right. I change my wording in the post. *DataTables is a bit tricky/special in some situations. The removal of the rows is for better performance when dealing with large tables and also handling server-side processing of the data-set*

Comment: @Sparky Thank you for your detailed answer, I really appreciate it. As of now I have it working with a hidden checkbox outside the DataTable binded with a custom jquery validation function that checks for whether the table is empty and has no checkboxes selected. Is that such a terrible workaround?

Comment: @BigMon, meh... I'm not a fan of these kinds of workarounds as the checkbox outside of the table has no practical meaning in the context of validating the user's form entries.  However, what choice do you have?  If it were my project, I would not remove input elements from the DOM in the first place... I'd hide them.  Otherwise, if that is unavoidable, I'd write custom validation from scratch since most the default abilities of the jQuery Validate plugin would be bypassed anyway.

Comment: @BigMon. FWIW, the idea of a hidden checkbox seems silly.  If it's hidden, the `input` is pointless as a `type="checkbox"`.   Just use a `type="hidden"` instead as that's what it's for.

Comment: @Sparky I agree with you on that one. Could you bind jQuery validation on a function instead of an input? Also, the only reason I'm using a `type="checkbox"` and not `type="hidden"` is because when I do `$('form').data('validator').settings.ignore = ':hidden:not("#cbApplicationSelected")';` and add the rule: `$('[name="cbApplicationSelected"]').rules('add', { noApplicationSelected: "error" });` with a `type="hidden"` it doesn't work, while a `type="checkbox"` works fine when wrapped in a div with `class="hidden"`

Comment: @BigMon, well, you're definitely doing something very wrong as that basic code works fine for me:  https://jsfiddle.net/9dn0p6bg/  Check what you're doing inside the `.rules()` method....  the `key:value` pairs represent `rule:parameter`.    Why `noApplicationSelected: "error"` when it should simply be `required: true`.   And no... why/how would you bind validation to a function?  That doesn't even make any sense.  You bind data validation to form input elements.  Anyway... way too much time spent on this unusual edge case.

Comment: Given the original question and considering the details I posted, I think you should accept my answer (No, you absolutely cannot bind validation to any element that does not exist in the DOM) or at the very least post a very detailed accounting of your workaround with a demo.